# ios open modal from segue from a programmatically created button?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am creating a button and added it to my toolBar like this:

```
UIButton *sendButtzon = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
sendButtzon.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
[sendButtzon setTitle:@"More" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
sendButtzon.frame = CGRectMake(toolBar.bounds.size.width - 18.0f,
                              6.0f,
                              58.0f,
                              29.0f);
[toolBar addSubview:sendButtzon];
```

How can I open a new viewController (which i have a segue for named "MoreView")?

Answer (score 3):

You implement the following action method:

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton*)sender
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MoreView" sender:sender];
}
```

And link this to your button like so (add this line to the code in your question):

```
[sendButtzon addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

This causes a tap on the button to call the `buttobPressed:` method, which in turn performs the segue which you have defined in the storyboard.

Comment: I am getting this error `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<ConvViewController: 0x8c73b50>) has no segue with identifier 'MoreView'`

Comment: Oooops i had missed to actually link the two views in the IB!! :) Thanks a lot man it works great now

Comment: In that case the segue either hasn't been defined, or is defined from a different view controller.

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to define an segue with name "MoreView" in story board.

or else you have to create UIViewControler on button click like this..

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton*)sender
{
   UIViewController *destinationController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
   [self presentModalViewContrller:destinationController animated:YES];
}
```

or Create View Controller form story board.

```
 -(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton*)sender
{
   UIViewController *destinationController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewContrllerWithIdentifier:@"DestinationViewController "];
   [self presentModalViewContrller:destinationController animated:YES];
}
```

Every UIViewController story board has property.